# Unable to use pygames collidepoint with other classes

Tags: python, pygame

I've had some problems using Pygame's `collidepoint` method through another class:

```
if(mouseclick[0]):
    for tile in self.engine.level.levellist:
        if tile.collidepoint(mousepos):
```

This small and easy code gives me an error:

```
if tile.collidepoint(mousepos):

AttributeError: TileClass instance has no attribute 'collidepoint'
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Been awhile since I used python and I'm probably just missing some easily fixed.

Comment: Where is `TileClass` defined? You just haven't given it a `collidepoint` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

`collidepoint` is a method of the `Rect` class.

Your `TileClass` has no `collidepoint` (that's what the error tells you), but if it has a `rect` attribute (since this is needed for `Sprites`), you're code should probably look like:

```
if(mouseclick[0]):
    for tile in self.engine.level.levellist:
        if tile.rect.collidepoint(mousepos):
```

But you didn't show your `TileClass` class, so this is just a guess.